How to handle deletion of content editable false span within contentEditable div?
this is how my React component looks like -
<div id="test" class="content-editable" contenteditable="true">hi! <div>welcome to&nbsp;</div><div><span contenteditable="false">hey|test('<span class="editable-cas-skip" contenteditable="true">default</span>')</span><br></div></div>

when I hit backspace, and the cursor is at the end of the  then it should delete the whole span.

You can achieve this via adding key.down event listener to identify it at the end of the span if so delete the span.
Refer the below code for reference:


import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const ContentEditable = () => {
  const contentRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
      if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        if (!selection.rangeCount) return;
        
        const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
        const { startContainer, startOffset, collapsed } = range;
        
        if (collapsed && startContainer.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && startContainer.hasAttribute('contenteditable')) {
          const lastChild = startContainer.lastChild;
          
          if (lastChild && lastChild.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && lastChild.hasAttribute('contenteditable') && lastChild.getAttribute('contenteditable') === 'false') {
            if (startOffset === startContainer.childNodes.length) {
              e.preventDefault();
              startContainer.removeChild(lastChild);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };

    const contentEditableElement = contentRef.current;
    if (contentEditableElement) {
      contentEditableElement.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
    }

    return () => {
      if (contentEditableElement) {
        contentEditableElement.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      id="test"
      className="content-editable"
      contentEditable="true"
      ref={contentRef}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: 'hi! <div>welcome to&nbsp;</div><div><span contenteditable="false">hey|test(\'<span class="editable-cas-skip" contenteditable="true">default</span>\')</span><br></div>' }}
    />
  );
};

export default ContentEditable;




Doesn't work. Having a nested contentEditable true within contentEditable false span is the problem.
